# Custom domain stopped working: Not found error showing

Tags: tumblr

I have using the custom domain feature of tumblr. I am writing my own blog, own content. No rebloging. Suddenly, it stopped working today and giving me a Not Found error.

the nslookup of my blog shows,

```
userccc:~$ nslookup mysite.com
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mysite.com
Address: 66.6.44.4

userccc:~$ nslookup mysite.tumblr.com
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   mysite.tumblr.com
Address: 66.6.36.57
```

Any idea what should I do now?

Comment: Does Tumblr use eNom for custom domains?  I saw something about Blogger users with domains fro eNom having problems, could this be related.    (I'm not familiar with Tumblr, so don't know the details.)

Comment: @MaryC.fromNZ I bought my custom domain from another company. My site came back, but it is again getting off time to time.

Comment: Are you using a DNS such as Cloudflare on your domain?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put point CNAME record to `domains.tumblr.com` for `www` and change your custom domain with adding www as the record. eg: www.domain.com